# Disabling right click context menu on a HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Making a painting app using HTML5 and Canvas.

I think I want to have a similar system to applications like Paint and Photoshop where you can have a primary and secondary color selected and use left click to paint with the primary color and right click to paint with the secondary color.

However, after one releases the right mouse button the context menu in the browser is brought up (view image, save image, select all).

Can this be elegantly disabled? I don't want it to be a hackish solution that only works on some browsers if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**You can use this:**

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/hpUWD/2/)!

**With the lastest jQuery:**

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e){ return false; });
```

**Note:** You should use something narrower than `body` if possible!

**Or without jQuery, applying on canvas:**

```
canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }
```

---

### EDITED

Updated the [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/hpUWD/) to show the contextmenu being limited to the canvas and not the image.

**JQUERY**

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', '#myCanvas', function(e){ return false; });
```

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<img src="http://db.tt/oM60W6cH" alt="bubu">
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising! Are there any differences between the two?

Comment: @RyanPeschel , I've updated the answer with an example for the limitation to the canvas element, leaving the browser `contextmenu` available for the image bellow the `canvas`.

Comment: Without jQuery:

canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
};

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
canvas.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Did not work because body already got the event and shows the context menu. Yet you can use this event if you have a custom context menu for this canvas. ;)

Answer (score 19):

This will disable the context menu on the canvas.

```
<canvas oncontextmenu="return false;"></canvas>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Clear, simple, effective.

Answer (score 10):

This should do the job with more modern (and readable) syntax than the other answers.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.oncontextmenu = () => false;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try adding `oncontextmenu="return false;"` on the body tag. It should disable the context menu.

If I believe this source : http://javascript.about.com/library/blnoright.htm which is google's first result to the query "javascript disable right click" that you should have tried.

Edit :

- about canvas I don't know the element, but did you try calling
  `stopPropagation()` on the event element once your function ends ?
- or the previous solution on the canvas tag instead of the body...

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it seems to disable right click on the entire page. I only want it disabled for this one canvas.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question requirement!He clearly started he only wanted it on a specific element.

Comment: Yes apparently, I edited the answer... adding infos on what has already been tried could help.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding dependence on Jquery Js, I have tried the preventDefault event not only with canvas but also in other elements. Regarding the crossBrowser I reviewed this page: [Events - Contextmenu](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html).

You probably need a validation of items that return undefined but it serves as a demonstration.

```js
(function(w, d){
 d.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event){
  var blockContext = [
   { type: 'tag', value: 'canvas'},
   { type: 'id',  value: 'fooId'},
   { type: 'tag',  value: 'img'},
  ];
  blockContext.map(
   elm => {
    var _elm
    
    if(elm.type == 'tag') _elm = d.querySelector(elm.value);
    if(elm.type == 'id') _elm = d.getElementById(elm.value);

    if(event.target == _elm) event.preventDefault();
   }
  );
 });
})(window, document);
```

```css
canvas {
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/>
<p id="fooId">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget lorem luctus nisi fermentum imperdiet in ac tortor. Vestibulum interdum risus vitae metus finibus pretium. Nullam facilisis lacus nec pellentesque faucibus. In tempus lorem ut mi sodales, vitae scelerisque quam pretium. Duis venenatis enim in nunc laoreet venenatis. Aliquam at magna vitae purus tincidunt posuere. Donec dictum pharetra ipsum, eu auctor lorem aliquet vitae. Donec faucibus metus quis laoreet ultricies. Aliquam aliquet, lectus a tempor tristique, diam sem auctor felis, sed ultrices magna nunc ut sem. Curabitur congue diam lacinia risus sodales luctus. In nec maximus ex. Nulla ultrices diam a erat imperdiet, nec convallis nisl pulvinar. Etiam quis placerat arcu, eu elementum felis. Phasellus lectus massa, faucibus faucibus nibh ut, dignissim tempor neque.
<p/>
```