# Canvas, disable image download

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a game in html5/js, there is a map with a fog of war on it.
When you right click on the canvas you can save the canvas as an image and so, you can have the whole map in a jpg, but that map need to be hidden.

Is there any trick to disable this ?

I tried to create my fog of war in the same canvas than the map, it works but it's harder to move the fog since i need to create for every move the entire map.

Thank you.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864249/disabling-right-click-context-menu-on-a-html-canvas

Comment: i already rode this but it doesn't help me, this guy wanted to protect an image and answer was "watermak", it's not usefull for me.
Maybe i should try to get a nice fog of war script ?

Comment: There is no way to disable the save, that is what the answer is. Question I have is: why is the whole map loaded at once?

Comment: Good question, maybe i should to create only the map when the player is load... but when the player move, it's harder for me to create the portion of map needed. I used a matrix, but ok i think i will have to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Here’s how to moderately obfuscate your image:**

It works by scrambling your map so the casual user cannot easily view it.

- Slice your image vertically and horizontally into many pieces.
- Scramble all those pieces and create a new scrambled image from them.
- Serve that scrambled image to the web page (this scrambled image is unrecognizable to the user).
- Save the scrambling order in a JSON array so you can later descramble the image.

Obfuscating Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wWbt5/

[image]

When you need the image, unscramble it into an **in-memory canvas** that the user can’t see, but which you can programatically use in your game.

De-obfuscating Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UtN6g/

**Code for obfuscating**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    #obfuscated{border:1px solid blue;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/obfuscated.png";

    var verticalSlices=60;
    var horizontalSlices=60;
    var sliceCount=verticalSlices*horizontalSlices;
    var sliceWidth,sliceHeight;
    var slices=[];
    var json;


    function start(){

        // vars for slice sizes
        sliceWidth=img.width/verticalSlices;
        sliceHeight=img.height/horizontalSlices;

        // create a slices array to be used to scramble our image
        for(var i=0;i<sliceCount;i++){ slices.push(i); }
        slices=shuffle(slices);

        // scramble the original image
        var $obfuscatedImage=document.getElementById("obfuscated");
        $obfuscatedImage.src=obfuscate(img,slices);


        // create a JSON array used to descramble the image
        slices.unshift(verticalSlices,horizontalSlices);
        json=JSON.stringify(slices);

    }

    function obfuscate(img,slices){

        var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
        tempCanvas.width=img.width;
        tempCanvas.height=img.height;

        for(var i=0;i<slices.length;i++){
            var s=slices[i];
            var row=parseInt(s/verticalSlices);
            var col=s-row*verticalSlices;
            var x=col*sliceWidth;
            var y=row*sliceHeight;

            var canvasRow=parseInt(i/verticalSlices);
            var canvasCol=i-canvasRow*verticalSlices;
            var canvasX=canvasCol*sliceWidth;
            var canvasY=canvasRow*sliceHeight;

            tempCtx.drawImage(img,
                x,y,sliceWidth,sliceHeight,
                canvasX,canvasY,sliceWidth,sliceHeight);
        }
        return(tempCanvas.toDataURL());
    }


    function shuffle(array) {
      var currentIndex = array.length,temporaryValue,randomIndex;

      while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
      }
      return array;
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Before scrambling</p>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/koolaidman.png"><br>
    <p>After scrambling</p>
    <img id="obfuscated" width=300 height=300>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code for de-obfuscating**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    #obfuscated{border:1px solid red;}
    #clarify{margin:10px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid blue;}
    p{margin:10px;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // this json would be downloaded from the server
    // first 2 elements are images width,height
    // next 2 elements are #vertical,#horizontal slices
    var json="[60,60,734,418,14,393,2863,1779,3555,1208,1300,2715,2380,130,2082,2004,2882,2610,2816,2537,1578,815,571,1188,806,2554,2115,683,923,2049,2180,2429,1799,1185,1827,522,3061,1856,554,1455,1731,3140,831,2022,2983,3203,2350,1586,2320,3494,1946,2628,1424,1900,1027,791,1373,257,3501,1094,1458,3419,2122,858,2515,2312,3521,2795,224,2711,77,2885,1239,2035,1545,1370,2787,468,3579,780,504,2070,2584,1698,2652,898,2111,2305,2901,2929,2482,2193,725,134,2781,2871,2342,2621,2930,3370,169,3107,2695,2862,963,1099,2775,997,2850,1252,2667,1782,1917,61,2645,2788,879,1377,1663,2522,517,2595,166,2815,2510,2835,2538,3551,2011,2942,30,3308,285,2933,1758,2029,2569,220,1105,445,931,2017,153,1728,3407,1057,2163,1636,296,920,2663,995,51,1840,25,1030,3117,1935,840,986,1387,1084,1832,728,37,1551,3361,533,1927,2771,109,3428,2123,2265,277,2643,3587,2764,549,65,785,2943,1643,2453,2467,2906,2335,540,626,3021,1802,2984,1547,284,2125,860,383,2292,2264,350,3141,2670,1722,1440,203,250,2813,1470,1901,2893,1197,2206,3535,2583,1787,1659,1130,541,2524,1435,380,770,161,3038,1607,3257,2240,1175,3176,2750,3304,759,67,993,2964,1497,173,2155,2948,1695,384,472,991,838,1798,977,334,219,2425,2030,269,3206,2423,1925,2202,2099,2721,1087,3508,635,3078,2987,2045,292,3029,2279,2845,2659,2379,492,523,674,1825,887,2169,1328,81,2585,382,2572,2793,1464,3590,453,1134,2067,949,983,1620,2818,6,1820,821,295,1116,2976,544,1913,2562,3406,864,675,2002,967,2985,2710,1784,427,2495,1590,1721,3381,610,3373,3339,1803,1041,2087,1465,1390,1014,1289,1868,2221,1068,2498,183,1680,805,1703,3504,2656,894,1671,2928,3595,825,3068,1053,2109,1292,691,2271,1100,3578,2451,1344,771,3384,2526,692,2336,2037,570,1233,2566,1477,3192,479,3353,1639,1378,3447,2973,3136,2148,588,3042,131,3070,2574,214,2743,3239,1058,1844,1019,3041,656,1893,3193,1902,2065,1449,3470,2608,2655,1708,1374,987,3166,3055,2327,1234,1678,1980,71,807,2228,3033,779,218,1625,405,215,3253,652,3086,1810,1602,1536,2174,2371,1916,2219,3151,410,1683,2442,1195,1141,54,532,3479,1319,733,3365,762,2680,3536,3507,117,1701,68,3148,1904,2782,320,1706,1078,629,2727,3275,649,268,625,885,2796,2660,2358,3177,2962,458,2594,2903,1056,1872,1499,1970,2545,1808,2294,1236,3548,902,3028,2797,3005,1801,3040,3254,1610,2245,2196,695,3322,696,3224,3344,198,901,2431,1657,2323,1486,1874,727,835,355,2322,2356,29,2534,1736,3114,2809,2046,3415,2458,366,3152,2508,2803,1050,2950,2077,409,1525,2108,1073,2939,2470,3489,2722,553,3268,2927,3269,338,3119,1682,477,1543,3238,1841,247,3318,1245,1444,3472,2066,1419,2829,3292,1885,2814,2178,2536,3460,524,1022,1745,2870,3414,2746,196,3534,2765,503,2776,2398,1474,3382,1290,1381,3232,459,1488,1018,63,3317,2159,2491,1186,2246,332,3082,3399,2191,152,828,2755,3106,2034,2484,2044,837,3486,2095,1760,1672,3511,667,737,1270,489,3410,2958,1459,1447,658,2365,1155,406,2000,339,236,560,870,1855,984,1386,158,1230,1170,1184,3226,1190,2063,1986,3185,1365,1988,457,1069,1472,699,959,682,3374,665,1329,1891,331,713,1923,3325,133,801,1366,1354,1569,2362,1272,2587,2926,814,755,768,883,1691,3334,604,2657,1985,636,434,412,2133,3503,3433,359,3319,498,2786,1198,1015,596,2521,1003,443,1000,231,154,2306,1253,86,3490,347,2532,3385,341,1220,2339,115,221,2303,3455,87,2089,2837,1786,973,5,3026,2003,1582,3309,2623,1293,2644,439,2101,681,2579,2205,2907,992,2284,487,1035,3050,841,969,1127,786,2898,1807,1759,1392,563,2661,2839,1738,1911,2598,1598,1751,1132,2079,243,2844,2401,2434,2461,1644,1775,1107,619,2249,2040,2578,738,547,1343,1400,53,1221,1043,1651,140,3024,1737,3518,3421,3549,1360,1081,3083,2773,1243,3337,888,631,1023,240,505,416,2728,2188,904,1550,2696,2647,1984,72,2406,108,606,2481,3444,1249,804,2996,3388,2410,1850,1158,3454,3506,1238,2236,589,1422,1847,2293,2724,3347,1567,3483,2812,849,899,941,2462,2091,537,2012,632,543,594,1306,132,546,1060,2223,3516,1697,816,3345,2145,1848,436,2671,155,1889,2048,2262,3559,3532,138,1299,2020,1957,2974,1715,643,3487,1317,2714,2162,1355,1067,926,732,1924,2783,1712,2636,3393,3112,2672,3499,2998,1726,3517,1594,3378,494,2059,1282,372,3313,0,1217,469,47,2445,1573,3459,2673,2273,249,2924,3529,2653,1397,2993,2506,810,2033,1049,2607,736,3429,1498,3403,162,265,1036,297,2260,3163,2447,659,2408,1148,146,1336,2678,3002,3048,288,1382,1597,1596,1969,1313,1681,35,1570,1445,3289,1363,2693,1561,3446,988,1968,2274,426,317,151,2945,435,283,3213,2697,1304,915,2332,3488,1987,3052,3411,1599,2509,1884,2730,2143,2444,2965,209,2131,2217,597,2438,2717,2593,1476,874,1714,844,471,1711,2076,2861,730,2698,2136,1965,3044,2914,2010,395,2396,342,176,2208,404,2254,702,2860,1656,3387,1906,3165,2549,1990,402,2421,233,2977,1260,3181,668,1140,177,3510,2051,1244,1818,2119,276,1858,2807,1146,739,1725,689,1092,1205,62,1646,1061,2552,21,69,2347,2649,3074,763,3266,1291,2539,1592,2126,2156,85,1314,124,1413,1574,2859,2798,1418,255,262,3231,1534,2307,2602,3496,1066,703,129,990,976,3121,293,3178,2016,3586,1664,690,3564,3214,2664,2235,2469,1839,1468,1817,2688,3364,2519,1266,2075,280,2142,1052,1806,3468,3354,1204,2875,2616,2542,2426,462,767,1504,1967,186,1031,139,2455,1296,2094,748,181,3098,2369,962,3283,160,2770,2085,608,2681,637,1608,2684,1909,2194,333,421,1380,542,3270,502,3375,3088,3102,163,1702,1849,3079,241,2800,3592,2856,1614,2441,2792,362,3219,1833,1187,871,839,2904,377,2256,1177,1966,1432,407,223,3199,1750,3130,2128,3563,1995,3227,851,2955,1091,1206,1631,796,1804,1202,758,2517,892,583,534,3583,1405,2280,2096,996,707,2392,44,2233,708,1136,2646,2551,687,797,1108,1013,345,1478,206,3440,1615,2309,1042,3157,1368,414,1796,2211,2505,371,3366,2734,3204,1974,303,99,306,2622,1326,2759,3527,3060,1978,335,1516,3515,456,1025,2784,1944,1364,84,2824,1951,3331,2269,3229,440,3047,1527,2889,721,475,107,1033,1286,3442,290,1420,1649,1743,2563,2507,2560,447,2113,302,3105,394,1193,2995,793,1515,1753,1151,1961,776,3552,1934,3560,520,3127,2285,2372,1268,526,1626,2921,2573,2525,1017,679,2165,488,575,1992,2872,1182,3222,2118,200,2605,2344,3149,2780,2514,38,3343,2036,1757,2104,2489,2527,924,830,3260,2141,1879,2090,189,1425,968,323,45,2757,91,3402,1149,2544,907,519,3228,3320,2283,1189,3252,3296,929,98,2638,3473,1788,1568,254,1676,3377,803,2112,3565,650,1150,3220,389,159,3197,2922,777,1448,513,3108,2880,677,630,3174,1780,1496,1414,1771,2580,2114,3383,2363,1080,1345,1214,386,180,267,3427,1996,216,829,3333,1226,433,1399,551,1852,3543,1032,3080,1137,446,856,743,2502,211,3072,2042,2978,2589,896,1145,357,572,2459,18,424,1029,1218,611,2247,3312,3004,275,1938,2706,2951,2504,914,535,3264,3430,530,3567,697,2400,1886,3233,3056,2952,1932,2940,301,2762,3135,882,184,704,460,3404,1274,1859,419,3537,2319,126,210,2716,1223,1873,1383,2881,1687,2377,64,3299,2234,3371,2259,3491,2548,3216,3288,2864,2902,2412,1020,1789,1960,309,1822,989,3420,246,3550,94,3208,391,3066,694,567,2637,3110,3316,2232,1265,1878,1686,179,940,1231,197,2097,3310,1560,1555,1085,820,2308,1617,2739,1724,1371,1950,2994,1860,2912,745,2760,2842,1353,116,1929,2026,586,2740,644,654,222,1861,43,698,360,1410,1242,2752,2272,2954,516,2105,3011,2449,432,827,593,1263,2794,685,1521,672,1595,2050,282,1823,1907,2869,1532,964,1542,614,2361,673,1275,1295,1585,1423,370,194,1653,934,3327,3525,935,2375,500,978,1871,753,1143,2625,2226,2464,3512,686,3360,2250,2949,3104,859,3417,579,1501,788,3462,1310,2516,1369,2997,1830,2528,2705,576,1393,1097,1843,3568,2386,1979,3054,142,3432,11,1408,834,167,3182,919,2513,1565,2543,1396,289,846,3071,2190,2634,2890,1654,308,798,385,3300,847,2541,2222,1972,1064,3363,2183,1717,3392,1704,1997,3025,2330,2383,1046,510,3505,506,75,2189,59,234,2149,1908,425,1460,1763,917,1732,3037,2957,600,73,2021,639,4,2853,2956,1228,581,235,2577,897,3241,1010,3096,1669,2446,843,2744,1006,1247,298,318,590,1790,356,3556,2291,2052,455,950,928,2758,1748,832,558,1642,2735,373,1429,3195,3261,2774,1494,2564,3175,2990,3293,2820,2150,710,648,483,792,281,112,932,688,740,3009,980,2873,1120,884,1735,2936,1926,1919,1028,2296,528,826,2650,495,143,1710,3546,1142,1628,2238,1342,2691,1070,1538,1037,765,2738,3146,3243,582,1931,192,3031,1503,3596,340,1461,3582,3443,1021,592,2268,1240,947,3089,103,3425,1510,605,2328,2887,2171,1495,2062,187,1083,1835,1869,1674,2834,316,1616,664,3513,2290,3408,1887,2501,1153,263,1059,213,274,2179,1684,1766,878,1427,3523,3207,3187,165,3035,1943,56,1215,2354,2316,2699,1606,312,3372,2935,2821,105,2198,313,3217,2346,1385,1320,624,3201,607,819,1008,3120,2100,2364,1200,3557,2028,1635,701,1809,3014,2685,2486,2209,1795,128,3533,1707,2215,2353,1566,2281,2941,2687,3581,2056,3321,2960,3542,2025,2700,60,1584,1857,662,1696,3302,2008,2001,2999,2895,2415,3018,367,2253,1918,3113,1755,199,974,1912,1685,1655,775,2005,2405,239,3476,408,1530,444,756,813,2590,2499,2018,122,1211,365,2606,3013,3391,2060,430,1350,1783,3409,55,3158,259,811,1005,1248,188,794,1009,2391,42,19,3094,1739,1524,3368,817,3223,2015,324,1580,651,3335,1101,550,1241,2586,3524,812,1442,2753,3395,2480,1279,1824,1854,1553,464,1508,3099,1764,32,2175,1159,1256,481,3457,40,2258,3156,1587,1312,1109,2614,1890,3520,3526,3294,1229,2846,913,2243,2763,3190,2475,3036,2676,655,1002,952,3179,90,862,1630,319,2761,569,2531,1216,2932,17,2503,800,1601,3458,1308,1398,2210,754,2822,3186,1139,1791,1446,2098,1727,33,3336,387,2106,773,229,2629,1430,1668,3423,1777,2134,8,2843,2959,2966,1993,3017,2944,2666,508,3142,2511,3445,1451,938,3531,1471,865,3281,1409,2785,343,2874,1812,195,2443,2799,2823,1040,1624,1981,1939,2277,633,2195,48,1280,3019,2212,562,1883,3084,2754,3144,3356,2988,2729,2014,3092,3218,1894,1352,1881,2876,2185,353,3541,2737,3032,1104,354,272,304,66,521,3075,1741,125,1358,3405,3237,2231,3128,3528,726,2418,2278,3295,2298,2474,3451,2244,3064,12,1514,2867,1255,2806,2064,2216,2384,1115,201,411,3398,2747,975,82,3571,930,1431,1112,212,1834,599,2310,909,615,620,1346,1641,1752,3396,1761,906,718,1517,2313,2550,3477,2349,2337,328,2257,2953,1562,463,2027,2092,2239,1039,363,757,536,149,1716,1746,3129,2603,1088,1914,1942,1920,135,2170,706,3150,2991,3081,305,1921,3389,1133,886,2352,2896,1123,2766,2838,670,2255,958,2261,653,2512,1571,1401,2397,869,2967,3180,1520,1165,3154,13,921,1619,3262,774,1492,2810,1126,1540,3173,2424,3212,1340,2732,2640,2329,2718,912,548,2289,2769,2225,3593,3562,2242,641,3251,1774,1507,3561,557,2600,1335,3452,999,2200,1307,722,2385,3573,512,1347,1880,465,3340,1324,480,3397,1947,1489,939,2229,2132,2472,2615,3030,2378,617,1537,2460,2970,484,2227,908,3509,256,3171,2620,1160,2493,2127,315,2428,731,3122,1318,127,3456,3111,242,1191,1095,2751,1899,781,3514,1800,3413,2868,556,2897,1453,3500,1167,2547,2686,2158,417,3100,2124,3126,2057,3067,3095,1544,1634,3589,2963,3475,1456,2341,3247,3244,193,1176,1034,2571,3077,174,2355,1793,1161,3230,1156,2043,3161,1232,2931,3282,1213,119,2858,2479,2971,1093,57,1720,1756,482,2599,2852,337,3278,93,2731,1278,1618,1379,1679,848,497,1327,1166,2402,3245,1235,1637,1331,3118,3301,3390,2009,3519,1152,1838,1563,3449,3478,1183,3349,2961,1341,3467,2448,1439,3277,3352,2888,397,486,2662,2144,1518,751,2604,2690,714,299,3246,172,2172,1945,2302,3545,2778,27,1633,2866,2567,2854,1315,3159,741,1867,118,442,120,2749,2918,3012,2989,352,1124,145,1322,660,618,1225,31,1281,876,943,3341,1949,1001,861,1103,2836,1846,2184,2613,3437,2492,1533,1754,3191,110,3324,2849,2490,3291,3093,3287,2756,3139,1044,1224,2708,2478,1194,1388,3039,3438,364,609,3234,3279,3290,3553,1482,3436,1851,228,3020,2237,1539,2840,1303,1403,2588,1956,2617,3285,1391,2768,2177,1121,1250,971,3001,2083,1958,1402,1837,2831,2910,1473,3394,1826,1487,1237,245,1273,2207,822,49,953,782,399,552,1119,3085,1321,1892,428,1222,1467,2427,2597,1842,3027,3103,1588,1209,3065,2630,3116,1147,783,3087,3584,2160,237,390,3357,1259,2833,1792,1576,3485,2804,2435,538,1948,136,1098,2468,501,1012,3131,3376,168,853,1660,2972,529,202,1629,2376,3284,711,420,3069,866,3,3265,2315,1662,602,1898,2203,438,2031,3259,3386,3539,2192,1558,1433,1438,1173,2683,1074,1375,1122,351,2382,2665,329,2032,16,1575,2674,3591,3298,616,1129,944,2791,1814,555,717,2825,346,545,2023,2618,3057,2287,875,1316,2168,1897,3062,647,1111,392,83,1667,3401,1484,1062,1666,1700,880,2321,1079,3481,2635,1862,3205,2173,89,2387,2072,248,1131,1048,3424,1169,584,2357,3492,2393,3000,3585,3091,836,833,1276,7,966,190,1125,2404,123,2317,1816,369,3314,2805,2137,927,2399,2071,1954,661,1600,1928,3183,1277,2633,2592,1729,1251,2340,1876,628,401,1612,2624,2969,561,872,1661,752,1593,2324,2161,595,693,3273,1463,1180,1579,1529,2186,2726,3271,720,750,2851,933,3023,2601,2982,1411,2288,1933,2692,1941,700,3015,2345,2947,1264,121,141,2556,2120,719,2409,2440,577,448,603,1246,1485,3169,3016,1577,2359,207,1016,2078,2916,2038,291,1513,70,2301,705,1797,2886,2024,2394,1457,2654,2934,2456,2197,3125,2351,646,2865,2039,2658,2373,3090,799,3097,2166,1936,114,3577,678,3572,1767,2553,2923,2827,2500,621,2979,2454,2847,585,2980,937,769,3249,3569,2925,1287,784,2789,893,1096,2367,2102,1407,2086,809,3184,881,2167,330,1971,1778,3359,3346,2275,954,3530,645,2748,1613,1940,1903,2801,2333,910,1367,1953,2187,3123,2299,2414,2214,936,2152,3200,3358,1583,3101,1301,2463,1977,1718,3580,1813,2381,965,3034,877,2055,1603,2709,1416,3576,226,1535,2619,922,1384,3422,2436,3155,1528,1658,3297,1768,3196,1437,78,790,1026,2248,1853,3426,1434,747,2477,3305,2533,2295,3453,2675,1421,1011,2325,1311,3272,1611,2297,1552,1689,461,449,2736,956,2857,3469,3006,787,657,92,3172,3342,527,217,1297,2596,2992,1910,850,15,1,2314,2520,2892,2088,3380,2213,3330,9,287,3276,3326,310,400,1284,1404,178,2819,749,1082,1922,3493,3463,1271,2848,1483,863,2061,3497,942,985,2631,574,1794,1086,204,2331,244,1212,1475,422,573,3441,104,566,634,97,1135,2390,205,1323,3188,1955,423,41,1436,2366,981,273,666,171,3306,1509,3362,2570,1359,2103,1983,2334,2832,845,2006,1522,2712,1866,3209,2703,1332,52,1412,873,1339,1075,1045,22,3147,3058,2266,1815,150,3124,378,3597,1334,191,322,1719,1179,2286,321,258,1090,1454,2891,2627,1181,1203,314,1531,1749,474,1462,311,2130,1877,39,3109,1744,2074,3221,3307,2450,2841,1976,2007,2884,3482,2073,1007,2485,684,2487,185,1638,1690,80,1652,175,2466,2407,1650,957,2081,2720,2612,451,1875,3225,3598,478,948,1937,490,824,868,358,1962,2968,2981,2154,1362,3133,466,2121,945,1994,2779,2557,2611,325,2725,3435,2915,2370,1915,2138,3202,1267,1819,1443,2058,1077,2181,2304,1773,1071,2374,1288,627,2591,715,111,3594,3168,3007,2555,3003,476,1785,1895,260,336,2439,709,766,1210,772,916,671,1675,467,3143,3137,2182,1227,1452,2348,2053,1394,587,1257,1554,101,3329,1376,1609,2641,2911,1357,1441,398,1479,1038,3063,2201,2080,2609,2420,2719,2360,3544,182,2668,925,2,327,271,1258,2224,2937,1480,2559,2437,3484,3132,1178,998,3369,3242,2494,266,96,2772,2252,3049,1219,34,1709,2877,3461,3022,1110,2855,1171,960,403,1964,890,1905,2777,1623,2395,3043,137,1930,3051,2069,3348,2338,1677,1648,3211,1742,1294,1556,746,415,1772,3502,1113,3498,2054,994,3400,1762,1734,441,3236,1076,2430,58,50,1506,1673,36,1469,1559,2117,3073,2452,156,1828,3465,3053,3566,2639,1500,344,1262,1428,1254,1157,1557,1163,1870,3547,431,493,1882,1694,2241,3522,2701,3194,1776,2311,2518,2084,539,1349,3045,452,1298,2389,2626,663,742,2689,955,1831,23,979,1836,642,1581,3323,509,716,429,1426,496,1589,1888,591,3540,348,157,1333,764,802,1963,2476,2733,1269,1283,413,1999,2568,1692,867,1829,559,106,2135,3554,2019,3418,2808,3570,28,2826,2648,1505,454,2047,2632,1647,2417,1481,3059,2107,1330,1138,1491,2679,905,2218,1896,1199,564,2811,1406,1564,450,3153,2270,680,2068,951,601,1054,808,2830,1548,1765,3170,113,3367,2116,565,2326,3160,2497,1730,88,1863,2878,1989,24,375,294,278,2529,2013,1781,232,1733,2742,580,2457,3332,26,1490,3115,1309,1065,598,3351,1770,3466,970,1395,1821,3350,3167,514,735,3046,3255,2905,1348,1172,1747,2920,147,2471,1769,2790,2139,2041,20,1952,891,2300,795,1864,1285,613,2176,638,2388,1196,1622,2473,676,612,2582,623,1811,2416,1670,396,2413,1356,1572,74,2157,3558,2411,3338,2707,2682,2110,2318,1337,918,2561,1519,1705,669,2164,1351,1604,2432,3416,1207,982,1665,2151,1063,3138,1523,2713,3235,1024,3575,972,2642,2879,3448,3495,3328,1982,2530,1627,1959,744,3240,3434,2129,1805,1723,1417,3280,2723,1493,2894,1713,76,900,2975,2433,854,10,760,100,3355,568,2546,1089,2147,2909,789,531,1415,46,307,3480,507,3164,2677,2419,3189,622,895,2488,2704,1174,3471,2465,1975,485,3248,3379,300,279,3474,1688,1192,170,286,2986,903,3303,3263,1128,2220,712,3315,2828,1621,1144,2343,491,2565,1305,578,729,3076,251,2483,1302,2767,818,3574,1164,2919,2946,1640,3267,525,1526,961,1004,857,2576,2917,470,2913,437,2496,723,144,1973,3210,2368,2282,2741,2651,2694,1512,2263,518,1605,381,3008,1201,95,225,2899,761,1699,368,1632,2251,2745,1502,3134,1991,640,1072,349,1511,1102,778,2802,852,388,1338,1051,1740,3450,1325,1114,1162,2153,2276,1845,3439,227,3464,3588,1549,252,2908,2669,2204,3286,1372,2540,2883,2523,3145,2146,946,1047,326,2558,238,724,889,3250,230,823,1154,2140,2199,1450,2575,511,1106,499,1361,1118,1389,3599,270,3538,3010,3256,253,2900,911,1865,102,515,1261,3311,3162,2093,1117,3431,264,3412,361,2230,2817,2403,208,3198,1693,1998,3274,2938,2267,473,3258,1055,842,2581,1541,148,2422,164,2702,379,79,1168,3215,1546,2535,1645,1466,261,855,1591,376,374]";

    var keys=JSON.parse(json);

    $button=document.getElementById("clarify");
    $button.style.display="none";
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        $button.style.display="block";
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/obfuscated.png";


    function deobfuscate(obfuscatedImage,keys){

        var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

        tempCanvas.width=obfuscatedImage.width;
        tempCanvas.height=obfuscatedImage.height;

        var verticalSlices=keys.shift();
        var horizontalSlices=keys.shift();
        var sliceWidth=tempCanvas.width/verticalSlices;
        var sliceHeight=tempCanvas.height/horizontalSlices;

        for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            var s=keys[i];
            var row=parseInt(s/verticalSlices);
            var col=s-row*verticalSlices;
            var x=col*sliceWidth;
            var y=row*sliceHeight;

            var canvasRow=parseInt(i/verticalSlices);
            var canvasCol=i-canvasRow*verticalSlices;
            var canvasX=canvasCol*sliceWidth;
            var canvasY=canvasRow*sliceHeight;

            tempCtx.drawImage(obfuscatedImage,
                canvasX,canvasY,sliceWidth,sliceHeight,
                x,y,sliceWidth,sliceHeight);
        }

        return(tempCanvas);
    }


    $("#clarify").click(function(){
        var canvas=deobfuscate(img,keys);
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="clarify">De-obfuscate</button>
    <p>The obfuscated image</p>
    <img id="obfuscated" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/obfuscated.png">
    <p>The de-obfuscated canvas</p><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's very impressive, thank you.

Comment: I made an node-module based on you answer https://github.com/webcaetano/image-scramble. 
And it use seed as map

Comment: Cool! Glad you found it useful :-)

Comment: With this approach, wouldn't you still be able to right-click and "Save Image As" on the descrambled canvas? So while the image returned from the server is still scrambled, it becomes very easy for the user to download the unscrambled image as you've done the work for them on the canvas?

Comment: The idea is that you wouldn't unscramble the image if the user wasn't authorized to view that image. ;-)

Comment: I would like to see this demo, but the image sources were hosted on Dropbox and seem to be deleted. Perhaps you can re-upload to a more permanent location and re-link.

Comment: It's very useful

Comment: Great example. There is an updated version [here](https://github.com/warren-bank/single-page-apps/tree/gh-pages/image-obfuscation). It's hosted on Github Pages [here](https://warren-bank.github.io/single-page-apps/image-obfuscation/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code may help:

```
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will disable context menu on a page. Instead of `document.body` you can write your canvas element:

```
document.getElementById('map_element').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

where `map_element` is ID of the canvas element

**UPDATE:**

but even this protection might be broken by executing in browser console:

```
document.getElementById('map_element').toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

I think the right decision is to download from server small regions of the map part by part

Comment: The problem is that an advance user can easily pass trough that script :/

Comment: @jacman this is a bad part of web development that all html, css, and js may be accessible by a user

Answer (score 0):

The first and the very simple way of doing that, would be the usage of **HTML5**

```
element {
  background-image: url('../link/to_image.png');
}
```

Which won't be saved if the user right-clicks the image and clicks Save Image as...But still remember that the user can get the image from Inspector!

This way, the image  won't be saved through right click atleast! And your map will be saved.

Second method is to use return of **JS** and stopping the event from occuring.

```
$('img').mousedown(function (e) { // mouse down on the image
   if(e.button == '2') { // if right click
     return false; // return nothing! :)
   }
}
```

This is the easy way, since you won't be require to update the background-image everytime! But, use what you like! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can prevent a user from saving what is already been downloaded to the browser.

You can make it "harder" for the user by adding a div on top over your canvas element and set its background to the image (or if possible just apply a css background to the canvas element itself).

You can disable the context menu as mentioned in another answer but the user can override this or use a browser that doesn't care (not sure if Opera has fixed this at the moment..).

You can also generate a bunch of layers and split your map file into many tiles, download those to the browser and draw a tile on separate layers. This is more complicated and makes it a bit more boring for the user to have to download all tiles and stitch them together.

But conclusively, no you can't prevent this - the user only need to go to console and network to find the downloaded image and save it out to the disk.