# prevent client from seeing image used in a javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an path to an image in my server. 
This paths is used by a javascript to load an image to use it in a canvas, in the following way:
the JS script draws the image in the canvas:
then it hides some parts of the image(by covering them with black layers)

**The problem** is that a user can read my js script to get the image url, and load it entirely(without the hidden parts)

Is there a way to solve this is issue that you can think off?

```
    imageMap.src = 'pathToJPGImage.jpg';
    imageMap.onload = function() {
      // this function draws black circles hiding areas of the map
      CoverHidenAreas();
    }
```

Comment: No, not with client side javascript. it can be manipulated by your users

Comment: I don't even need to read your JS source code to get the image. Instead, I can just go to Resources or Network in the Developer Tools can see the whole image. Client side is *never* safe. It's like trying to check password on client side. It just won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what server technology you're using, but if you need to dynamically cover parts of your image server-side there are some great libraries for that like https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Comment: Why not cover it at the server side and then send the image?

Comment: Thanks!  I  use PHP. I will probalby need to cut the image in squares) cause with cirlces is not possible in PHP I think. Using: imagecreatefromjpeg.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a javascript image scrambler you can use.  The scramble function works on an image element.  Be careful about getting into an onload loop. You can see that I scramble onload and then reset the onload to avoid looping when setting the new value.

```js
   function scramble(el) {
  // create a canvas element
  const V = document.createElement('canvas')

  // set the width and height of the canvas to be the same as the input image , then get the 2d context
  const W = V.width = el.width, H = V.height = el.height, C = V.getContext('2d')

  // draw the input image onto the canvas
  C.drawImage(el, 0, 0)

  var id = C.getImageData(0, 0, W, H), D = id.data, L = D.length, i = L / 4, A = []

  for (; --i;)A[i] = i
  function S(A) {
    let L = A.length, x = L >> 3, y, t, i = 0, s = []

    if (L < 8) return A

    for (; i < L; i += x)s[i / x] = S(A.slice(i, i + x))
    for (i = 4; --i;)y = [6, 4, 7, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2][i], t = s[i], s[i] = s[y], s[y] = t
    s = [].concat.apply([], s)
    return s
  }

  // get the pixel data of the image
  var N = C.createImageData(W, H), d = N.data, A = S(A)

  for (var i = 0; i < L; i++)d[i] = D[(A[i >> 2] * 4) + (i % 4)]
  C.putImageData(N, 0, 0)
  el.src = C.canvas.toDataURL()
}

function btnScrambleClick() {
  const srcImage = document.getElementById('srcImage');
  srcImage.onload = null;
  scramble(srcImage);

}

function previewFile() {
  const srcImage = document.getElementById('srcImage');
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    srcImage.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    srcImage.src = "";
  }
}

previewFile();
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"/>

<p>
<button id="btnScramble" onclick="btnScrambleClick()">Scramble / Unscramble</button>
</p>

<div id="main">
  <img id="srcImage" src="" alt="Uploaded image" onload="btnScrambleClick()">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thats great but still. if I put a break point, right after it enter to the function:
function btnScrambleClick(). 
Then i can see the clear image before it get altered rigth?

Comment: @GerardoGonzalez You could slow down snoopers even more by (1) Sending the image source as a base64 encoded string so there's no code resembling `.jpg` or `.png` extensions, (2) obfuscating (or even encrypting) that base64 string,  (3) sending the scramble-key-array in a separate JSON request,  (4) minifying & obfuscating your javascript so snoopers can't easily find a function named "scramble". However, this would not stop a determined hacker using a tool like Firebug to examine requests & responses.

Comment: @wolfhammer. Upvote for nice scrambler. I did something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973528/canvas-disable-image-download/20985155#20985155

Comment: @GerardoGonzalez .  I would load the image into the scrambler then save the scrambled image as the source.  Your game would load scrambled images and unscramble when they arrive. This would only stop the easy snooping on the urls.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. The client loads the image onto their computer to be processed by the canvas, so the client can intercept the image loading (or in this specific case, look at the image in their Resources tab of their developer tools) and copy the bits wherever they want.

If you have sensitive information, you want to do any processing of it on a computer you control. Given you are designing a website, you probably have access to a web server. Do the processing there.

Comment: OK thanks. I use PHP in the server side, not sure if I will be able to draw this mask  over the image before sending it to the server..

Comment: @GerardoGonzalez Havvy correctly says it's impossible to prevent a savvy user from viewing an image. To obscure parts of your image on the server, you can use `Node.js`. That's a server-side implementation of javascript -- including a plug-in that implements a canvas that you can use to alter your image and export it to an image that the server can deliver.

Comment: I'm sure there's modules that let you do canvas-like transformations to images in PHP too. At minimum there's ImageMagick.